# Proving naturality after determining a collection of isomorphisms.

Tags: category-theory, functors, natural-transformations

Let $F : C \to D, \ \ G : D \to C$ be two functors we're trying to prove are quasi-inverse to each other.

Suppose I've proved that $F \circ G(x) \simeq \text{id}_D(x) = x$ via the collection of isomorphisms $\alpha_x$.  In my particular problem $\alpha_x$ happens to be the unique such isomorphism.

How do I then show naturality or $\alpha_y \circ F\circ G(f) = f \circ \alpha_x$ for every $f : x \to y$ in $C$?

This is a question I had after another question and [partial answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3184753/26327), if that provides any necessary background info.

Comment: I am definintely not seeing this as trivial.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement : "if $F:C\to C$ is a functor and for every $x$ there is a unique isomorphism $\alpha_x : F(x)\to x$; then $(\alpha_x)$ is a natural isomorphism" is not true, so unless you have some more hypotheses we can't help you.

Here's a counterexample : let $C$ be a category with a unique object $*$ and two morphisms : $x,id$ with $x\circ x = x$. Then there is a unique isomorphism $*\to *$.

Now let $F$ be the functor that sends $x$ to $id$ (the rest is forced by the definition of functor- you may check that it does define a functor). Clearly it satisfies the hypotheses of the claim (because there is a unique isomorphism $(F(*)=*)\to *$), but this isomorphism is not natural, because $id\circ F(x) = id\circ id = id$ while $x\circ id = x \neq id$

Comment: The background info you're looking for is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3184557/theres-an-equivalence-of-simplicial-categories-delta-to-tilde-delta-tex/3184753#3184753
 $F = \varphi,  G = \psi$.